# Flutter InputFormatter filter counteracts MaskedInputFormatter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to create a phone number text field in the format '(###) ###-####' that only takes in numbers:

```
                TextField(
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  controller: PHONE_CONTROLLER,
                  autocorrect: false,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Phone Number'),
                  inputFormatters: [
                    MaskedInputFormatter('(###) ###-####'),
                    FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                  ],
                ),
```

However, after I added the filteringtextinputformatter the input field no longer formats the numbers this way, and also numbers are inputted in the wrong order.

What is the correct way to do this?